# Need to display same words to multiple users using socket.io and JS

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am making a multiplayer word game using javascript and socket.io, version 2.3.0. The game is basically just a 5x5 grid of buttons, each with a random word on it. I want to display the exact same words to each user. However, it is currently displaying different words to different users. Here's part of my code:

```
//index.js
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('displayWords', handleDisplayWords);
const wordArray = ["word1", "word2", "word3".. etc] //length of this is 400
let usedWords = [];
//out of the 400 words in wordArray, get 25 random ones without repeating
for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        let word = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)];
        if (!usedWords.includes(word))
        {
          usedWords.push(word);
        }
        else{
            while (usedWords.includes(word)){
              word = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)]; 
            }
            usedWords.push(word);
        }
}
const currUsedWords = usedWords;


function handleDisplayWords(){ 
  for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++){
    word = currUsedWords[i];
    var button = document.getElementById(i+1);
    button.textContent = word;
  }
}
```

```
//server.js
const io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', client => {

    client.on('newGame', handleNewGame);
    client.on('joinGame', handleJoinGame);;

    function handleNewGame() {
        let roomName = makeId(5);
        clientRooms[client.id] = roomName;
        client.emit('gameCode', roomName);
        client.join(roomName);
        client.number = 1;
        client.emit('init', 1);
    }

    function handleJoinGame(roomName){
        const room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomName];
        let allUsers;
        if (room) {
          allUsers = room.sockets;
        }
    
        let numClients = 0;
        if (allUsers) {
          numClients = Object.keys(allUsers).length;
        }
    
        if (numClients === 0) {
          client.emit('unknownCode');
          return;
        } else if (numClients > 2) {
          client.emit('tooManyPlayers');
          return;
        }
        clientRooms[client.id] = roomName;
        client.join(roomName);
        client.number = 2;
        io.emit('displayWords');      
    }
});
io.listen(3000);
```

The issue is that it comes up with a random 25 word list for each user, instead of using the same one. When I replace the line "const currUsedWords = usedWords;" in index.js with "const currUsedWords = ["word1", "word2",..."word25"];" it works how I want it to. How can I get a random list of 25 from the wordArray and have it just be defined as a constant and not change? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure whether `index.js` is on the client, but if you want all the clients to use the same words, generate them on the server and broadcast them to all clients. If each client generates their own words, well, there's the problem. The server would, at minimum, need to provide a seed to a PRNG to every client for that to work.

Comment: @ggorlen yeah forgot to mention index.js is on the client, I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a random array in the server side rather than client side and send it to the client when they connected.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I'll give it a try, thank you!